# Should development teams switch projects at the end of every deadline (sprint)?

Tags: management

At my current position, it's common for teams to completely switch projects and hand-off their tasks to another team even if there is no valid reason, such as the other team having more experience with the project.

The argument to this is that it keeps teams well aware of the entire ecosystem and adds redundancy. For instance, if someone goes on vacation there are now more candidates available to tackle the project.

Is this an acceptable approach to software development? To make the question less vague, I have certain specific questions:

- What are the correct situations where it is acceptable for to teams alternate projects?
- What are the pros and cons of having a specialized team devoted to one area?
- What are the pros and cons of having all team members learn different parts of the system?

I'm of the opinion that this is incorrect, because that means that there is less quality work and more downtime while team members relearn their respective projects. Thoughts?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Is it possible to shuffle team in between a sprint?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/198862/40980)?

Comment: How long are your sprints? 1 week is common and that would be a high turn over!!

Comment: There is an (obvious) trade-off here between "quality + efficiency" versus "spreading the knowledge".  Presumably, your management understand that trade-off; i.e. they are looking at a bigger picture than you are.  In short: it is only "clearly wrong" if you ignore the benefits of spreading the knowledge; e.g. the mitigating the risk of a key developer will leaving.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to call you naïve, but there is no *should* in software development. If you consult and travel as much as I have, you've seen a lot -- some of it absolutely mind-boggling. I wouldn't be surprised to stumble on a development shop where participants defend their ideas by fighting each other with sharp sticks, wearing diapers.

Regarding particulars,

Pros for switching:

- A more well-rounded developer
- Interchangeability
- Wide-area view
- Increased engagement because devs don't get bored

Pros for specialization:

- Deep knowledge
- Faster development in the specialized area

For cons, just flip the pros around.

Regarding quality, I've seen high quality code from both approaches. That's more a result of your team's dedication to quality than it is a side-effect of specialization.

Comment: This made me laugh. With my experience I've also come to take everything with a grain of salt. My question came about because I've noticed at my new contractual position my colleagues have very limited or little knowledge of the tech they work with and I'm wondering if the rapid context switching from one project to the next is responsible for this. But it may just be a variety of factors. Thanks.

Comment: I can relate to all of the points! I would add though as Cons: 1 - Feeling of not belonging to something; 2 - Fact 1 will make people think their work isn't relevant and they tend to not work hard on their tasks. This is happening right now at my workplace